# Empty version in List item version history

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, development

I have a custom list and Problem is even if I am not changing the data and click on save the new versions are adding in my version history with out any changes..

Is there  solution/code that it should update the version history only if the item(list row) is changed when we click on save button.

Comment: I have similar story.
It looks, that ver. 2.0 has no changes.
I expected to be created two versions based on 2 actions from user. Can you help me how to avoid it? [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRX7F.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRX7F.png)

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I cannot reproduce your issue. However the default behavior is the same as your expectation.

When the data is not changed, the version history is the same, while I change the data, the version history updates as shown below.

I'm using OOTB list , just some custom settings in my list.

[image]

My version settings:
[image]